# Google Chrome - how to make the video element exactly fitted into the layout?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have to rotate 3 deg the box to fit with layout white box. But when i apply rotate the borders of the video element is not smooth line how to fix it so that the borders are straight and it fits exactly 3 degree with the background layout?

[image]

(screen shot shows the white box by graphics designer the main layout, black box is the video container which is not fitting with the white box)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding:0px;
/*      overflow: hidden;*/
    }

    #lefttop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 495px;
  left: 57px;
  transform: rotate(3deg);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<html> 
<body > 

  <div id="portrait">
    <img src="images/sp_3/1.gif" />
  </div>


  <video id="lefttop" width="300" height="300">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

</body> 
</html>
```

EDIT: video element has to completely fit in white area (not like as it is now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work very nicely if you dispense with the background image gif and just remake the whole thing in CSS.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:377px; height:314px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 360px 157px, #EFA849 0, #D47339 100%);
}
#lefttop {
  width:300px; height:226px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:black;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 5px #7D4B22;
  transform:rotate(3deg);
  transform-origin:-280px 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <video id="lefttop">
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
</div>
```

(Note that I changed the dimensions to fit the size of your screen shot; you may have to changed them back to what you need them to be; it's unclear from your source what the actual sizes are.)